# Undefined symbol with compiled package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the pip module swigibpy. I installed it once before on a different system and it was fine, but for some reason it's no longer working.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Anaconda Python 3.5. I've installed ubuntu packages python-dev and g++.

I don't understand the nature of the error below. If you could give me any insight that would help me track it down, that would be a great help.

```
>>> import swigibpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/swigibpy.py", line 34, in <module>
    _swigibpy = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/swigibpy.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_swigibpy', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_swigibpy.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Answer (score 0):

your Anaconda `libgcc` might be outdated. try update it: `conda install libgcc`